# Liferay login using facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, liferay-6

I am trying to do **SSO** for liferay 6.1 via **facebook**. For that I have created App id and secret and have given them inside portal `settings--->authentication--->facebook`.

Now, if I am trying to login using facebook link it gives the following error inside pop-up -

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

I guess I need to provide my site url/domain in facebook somewhere itself. Can anyone help me out for the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In facebook developer section , you have to create one app and generate secret key and provide your domain name in its  setting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

**Solution**

- Go to your Facebook App
- Navigate to Settings
- In Basic tab, select +Add Platform
- Select "Website"
- Give your domain in Site URL (eg: localhost:8080)
- Save
- Enjoy !

**Tip:** If you want multiple people to login to your site, enable : "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" in **Status&Review**